# misassigned vertex names when building network object

Tags: r, networking

I am trying to create a network in R, using the network package.
This network contains isolates, which have NA in the "to" column of the edgelist. Therefore creating the network does not work (because of the NA values). I tried a workaround in which I created an empty network first, then added the vertices and then added the edges (see code below)

```
network <- as.network(matrix(0, ncol = 0, nrow = 0), directed = TRUE)
network <- network::add.vertices(network, nv = length(unique_nodes), vertex.names = unique_nodes)
network <- network::add.edges(network, edgelist_build$from, edgelist_build$to,
                              vals.eval = build_list)
```

The problem now is that the vertex indexing done by `add.vertices` assigns ascending numerical indices (`1:length(unique_nodes`), whereas the vertex indices in `edgelist_build` are numbers from empirical data in a different range. Consequently when trying to add the edges, I get

```
Error in add.edges.network(network, edgelist_build$from, edgelist_build$to,  : 
  (edge check) Illegal vertex reference in addEdges_R.  Exiting.
```

because some edges reference vertices that do not exist in `network`.

I tried setting `vertex.names = unique_nodes` which did not work and inspecting the network object (a `list`) I see that the referencing is still the same. I am not sure how to proceed with this.

You can replicate this issue as follows:

```
unique_nodes <- sample(1:100, 55, replace = TRUE)

num_edges <- 100 # Number of edges
from <- sample(unique_nodes, num_edges, replace = TRUE)
to <- sample(unique_nodes, num_edges, replace = TRUE)
edgelist_build <- data.frame(from, to)
edgelist_build <- edgelist_build[edgelist_build$from != edgelist_build$to, ]

network <- as.network(matrix(0, ncol = 0, nrow = 0), directed = TRUE)
network <- network::add.vertices(network, nv = length(unique_nodes), vertex.names = unique_nodes)
network <- network::add.edges(network, edgelist_build$from, edgelist_build$to)
```